# How can we add SOAP request Test step in a Test Case using groovy scripts

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am looking for adding a SOAP request Test step in a test case, from a different TestSuite and test case, i have already coded the part to add Groovy script for same requirement but not able to add a SOAP request test step. Any help?

following is my code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.GroovyScriptStepFactory

suite = context.testCase.testSuite.project.addNewTestSuite("AutomatedTestSuite")
tc = suite.addNewTestCase("automatedTestCase")
gs = tc.addTestStep( GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE, "GroovyScript1" )
gs2 = tc.addTestStep( GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE, "GroovyScript3" )
gs.properties["script"].value = 'log.info(\'hello world\')'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the another testSuite,testCase and testStep by it's name through project as follows:

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def testStep = project.testSuites['TestSuiteName'].testCases['TestCaseName'].testSteps['testStepName']
```

Or alternatively instead of array approach using `getXXXXbyName` method:

```
def testStep = project.getTestSuiteByName('TestSuiteName').getTestCaseByName('TestCaseName').getTestStepByName('testStepName')
```

Then to add this testStep to your testCase you can use [`cloneStep(WsdlTestStep testStep, String name)`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/WsdlTestCase.html#cloneStep(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestStep,%20java.lang.String)) method.

All together in your script:

```
def suite = context.testCase.testSuite.project.addNewTestSuite("AutomatedTestSuite")
def tc = suite.addNewTestCase("automatedTestCase")

// get desired testStep
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def testStep = project.testSuites['TestSuiteName'].testCases['TestCaseName'].testSteps['testStepName']
// add it to your new generated testCase
tc.cloneStep(testStep,testStep.name + "_Copy")
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

If instead of a copy of another SOAP testStep you want to create a new one, you can do it using the follow code. Take in account that to create a testStep of SOAP type more info is needed than when you create a groovy one due to the need for wsdl operation info (in the example we take the first one but if you've more than one take care of what you take).

IMO the first approach is simpler, you can copy another testStep and change the properties you want... anyway if you want to do it this way here you're:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory
def suite = context.testCase.testSuite.project.addNewTestSuite("AutomatedTestSuite")
def tc = suite.addNewTestCase("automatedTestCase")

// get the WSDL operation... for the example we take the first one
// however if you've more get the correct one
def operation = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceAt(0).getOperationList()[0]
// factory to create the testStepConfig
def factory = new WsdlTestRequestStepFactory()
def config = factory.createConfig(operation,'stepName') 
// create the testStep
def testStep = tc.addTestStep(config)
// change the request
testStep.properties['Request'].value = '<request>someData</request>'
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: I have one more question @albcliff is there any other way of getting project reference. I mean instead of def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

Comment: Also Cloning is not what i am looking for, i need to add a new Test step in another testsuite from one of my testsuite and in that test step should be SOAP request like i have added groovy script test step in m code

Comment: @Manoj you can use `testRunner` in the same way that `context` to get `project` but I think that you're asking for a more compact way... in a groovy testStep I think there isn't... at least I don't know how.

Comment: @Manoj despiste the name cloneStep of method it really creates a copy of a testStep, I purpose this solution since in the question seems that you want to copy a request from another testSuite not create a new one. Furthermore it's harded to do it adding a new testStep since you need to has more info (endpoint, method from wsdl...) and do more steps...